# Loading GeoJSON with complex "properties" object into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, geojson

I am attempting to load [Daylight OpenStreetMap data](https://daylightmap.org/) into BigQuery. I extracted just the buildings using Osmium and produced a ~600GB newline-delimited GeoJSON file. I uploaded this file to Google Cloud Storage and asked BigQuery to load it following the [Loading GeoJSON data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#geojson-files) page.

```
bq load \
  --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
  --json_extension=GEOJSON \
  --autodetect \
  dataset.table gs://redacted/planet-v1.35-just-buildings.osm.jsonl
```

When I execute the command, it gives me an error:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r4fac8ff7d697a347_0000018c3b525294_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'redacted:bqjob_r4fac8ff7d697a347_0000018c3b525294_1': Error while reading data, error message:
Failed to parse JSON: Top-level GeoJson 'type' member should have value 'Feature', but was
'supermarket'.; ParsedString returned false; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Parser
terminated before end of string File: planet-v1.35-just-buildings.osm.jsonl
```

There are indeed lines of GeoJSON in this file where the `properties` object has `"type":"supermarket"` – that is valid GeoJSON and should be parsed as such.

For example, this row of GeoJSON will not correctly parse with the `json_extension=GEOJSON` option.

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"a31387138","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[8.9979793,48.6337255],[8.9980396,48.6331225],[8.9981886,48.633129],[8.9984096,48.6332205],[8.9984021,48.6332949],[8.9984343,48.6332963],[8.9984226,48.6334125],[8.9983935,48.6334112],[8.998374,48.6336055],[8.9983188,48.6336031],[8.9983141,48.6336502],[8.9981094,48.6336412],[8.9981004,48.6337308],[8.9979793,48.6337255]]]]},"properties":{"@type":"way","@id":15693569,"@version":20,"@changeset":98029821,"@uid":12169583,"@user":"davidfaure_bot","@timestamp":1611423696,"wheelchair":"yes","type":"supermarket","toilets:wheelchair":"no","shop":"supermarket","phone":"+49 7031 744677","opening_hours":"Mo-Sa 08:00-21:00; Su,PH off","name":"EDEKA Markt Hacker","building":"store","addr:street":"Alemannenstraße","addr:postcode":"71155","addr:housenumber":"1","addr:country":"DE","addr:city":"Altdorf"}}
```

How can I get this data loaded into BigQuery?